# Spark driver throws weird exceptions when Spark standalone cluster is not available

Tags: java, apache-spark

Spark version : 1.4.1

I am running below driver program and try to create a Spark Context for a remote spark standalone cluster. At the time remote spark cluster is not available following errors are reporting by the spark. What would be the reason for exceptions (

```
ERROR OneForOneStrategy: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
```

) and how I could eliminate them ?

Note : when I am using running local or remote standalone cluster, my application is working fine.

### Java Program

```
public class SparkContextTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaSparkContext sc = null;
        try {
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("testABC");
        conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR");

        conf.setMaster("spark://remote-server:7077")
                .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "false")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
                .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "1g");

         sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        } catch(Exception e){                
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(null != sc){
                sc.clearCallSite();
                sc.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Spark log

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/downloads/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/downloads/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-examples-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/12/09 17:11:23 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.1
15/12/09 17:11:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/09 17:11:24 WARN Utils: Your hostname, pesamara-mobl-vm1 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.30.9.107 instead (on interface eth0)
15/12/09 17:11:24 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/12/09 17:11:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: pes
15/12/09 17:11:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: pes
15/12/09 17:11:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(pes); users with modify permissions: Set(pes)
15/12/09 17:11:26 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.30.9.107:55740]
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 55740.
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/blockmgr-3226ed7e-f8e5-40a2-bfb1-ffabb51cd0e0
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 491.5 MB
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/httpd-7f2572c2-5677-446e-a80a-6f9d05ee2891
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 45047.
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.30.9.107:4040
15/12/09 17:11:29 INFO FairSchedulableBuilder: Created default pool default, schedulingMode: FIFO, minShare: 0, weight: 1
15/12/09 17:11:29 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:11:29 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:11:29 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:11:49 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:11:49 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:11:49 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:12:09 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:12:09 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:12:09 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:12:29 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/12/09 17:12:29 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.30.9.107:4040
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/12/09 17:12:29 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AppClient.scala:160)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor.aroundReceive(AppClient.scala:61)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:12:29 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:12:29 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54184.
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54184
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.30.9.107:54184 with 491.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.30.9.107, 54184)
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/12/09 17:12:30 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.SparkContextTest.main(SparkContextTest.java:32)
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.SparkContextTest.main(SparkContextTest.java:32)
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: path = /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/blockmgr-3226ed7e-f8e5-40a2-bfb1-ffabb51cd0e0, already present as root for deletion.
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/httpd-7f2572c2-5677-446e-a80a-6f9d05ee2891
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8
```

Comment: Check Spark URL in your UI, Is it same that you are passing **spark://localhost2:7077** ?

Comment: yep. It;s just to simulate unavailable remote spark standalone cluster. I changed it to spark://remote-server:7077 Hope now it more clear.

Comment: I am confused. What exactly do you expect when cluster is not available?

Comment: I expect Spark to gracefully shut down context. In this case it throws misleading exceptions.

Comment: @era It is been a long time but did you or anyone solve this problem? I am facing this currently.